# Big Custom Notification did not display as i want

Tags: android

I want to create a notification like this

[image]

I'm using RemoteViews, this is my **custom_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:background="#524E4D">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_noti_song_cover"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:background="#f441"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_noti_song_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Hello World"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/img_noti_song_cover"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_noti_artist_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_noti_song_name"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/img_noti_song_cover"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="fdsgsfgdfhdf"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#DDD7D5" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_line"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/img_noti_song_cover"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_noti_artist_name"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/horizontal_line"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/img_noti_song_cover"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ic_noti_previous"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_notification_previous"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ic_noti_play"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_notification_play"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ic_noti_next"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_notification_next"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the code to display the notification

**MyNotification.java**

```
//create song playback notification
private void createSongPlaybackNotification() {

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, getString(R.string.playback_channel_id))
            .setCustomBigContentView(getRemoteView())
            .setContentTitle("SongPlayback Notification")
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.arrow_up_float)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_playback_notification_icon))
            .setContentText("this is content text")
            .setSubText("sub text")
            .setOngoing(true);

    playbackNotification = builder.build();
}

//create remote view
private RemoteViews getRemoteView() {

    songPlaybackRemoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.player_notification);
    updatePlaybackNotificationUI(songPlaybackRemoteViews);

    Intent actionPlaybackIntent = new Intent(ACTION_PLAYBACK);
    Intent actionNextIntent = new Intent(ACTION_PLAY_NEXT_SONG);
    Intent actionPreviousIntent = new Intent(ACTION_PLAY_PREVIOUS_SONG);

    PendingIntent playbackPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, actionPlaybackIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    PendingIntent playNextPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, actionNextIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    PendingIntent playPreviousPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, actionPreviousIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    songPlaybackRemoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.ic_noti_play, playbackPendingIntent);
    songPlaybackRemoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.ic_noti_next, playNextPendingIntent);
    songPlaybackRemoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.ic_noti_previous, playPreviousPendingIntent);

    return songPlaybackRemoteViews;
}
```

When i ran the app, it displayed not exact what i want

[image]

it was cropped by half, just like the standard height of usual system notification. I have searched many threads to find the solution but yet still found anything helpful. I have also tried both **setContent(remoteViews)** and **setBigCustomContentView(remoteViews)** but still the same

Comment: I have not tested on Android O yet, im testing on my Android 5.1 (Lollipop). I call the notify when i press play next/previous song